# Which bootloader that Unetbootin uses?

Tags: usb, boot-loader, bootable, unetbootin

I used Unetbootin to make a bootable USB. The installing process consists of 4 step, one of them is "Installing Bootloader". I wonder which Bootloader Unetbootin has used because I want to try to install it in manual by myself on my usb?

Comment: As far as I know, it installs the bootloader from the distribution of your choice, or from the .iso file.

Comment: @schaiba Unlike most installation USB creators, UNetbootin installs a different bootloader than the one in the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

UNetbootin uses the SYSLINUX bootloader.

Comprehensive instructions are available here http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX